# Approval process via email service

Tags: approval-process

[image]I need your help.I am parsing approval email response via email service.Everything is working as expected. But When I am sending any record for approval and then Assigned approver is replying through email as Approve or Approved, the record got approved but in Approval history section my name is coming as actual approver all the time.I tried many things but it's not working.How to change actual approver based on who is replying to that email.I see some people faced same issue but I didnt see any work around.Please see attached for more details

code snippet

```
 if(firstLine.containsIgnoreCase('Approved') || firstLine.containsIgnoreCase('Approve') || firstLine.containsIgnoreCase('OKAY') || firstLine.containsIgnoreCase('YES')) {
                    approvalreq();         
                    }
public void approvalreq(){
    List<ProcessInstance> pi =[SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObjectId=:recordid];
    List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> piw =[SELECT Id,ActorId,ProcessInstanceId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstanceId=:pi[0].Id];
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 =new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req2.setAction('Approve');
        req2.setComments(secondLine);
        req2.setWorkitemId(piw[0].Id);

        Approval.ProcessResult result2 =Approval.process(req2);     
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi Ritika,   I have updated question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The standard functionality to allow a user to approve by responding to an email is called  [email approval response](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_email_approval_faq.pdf).

By using the standard functionality, you don't need to set up your own email service to handle the emails or parse the response for "approved"-like keywords, and the user sends the email will be recorded as the approver in the approval process history.

Comment: Hi Martin      I need to parse additional keywords  also like Okay or I am Okay. Dat's why I am using email service

Comment: @Ayush no matter who sends the email, the inbound email handler will be run with the admin as the context user and all actions will be recorded as being done by the admin.

Comment: clarification -- email service running user is the context user defined in the metadata, not necessarily an admin; more likely a headless user

Comment: good point, the context user doesn't have to be an admin @cropredy

Comment: @ Martin @ Cropredy  - That means in approval history actual approver will be a context user ? We can't set that to user that is replying to that email ,will be a actual approver?

Comment: @Ayush right, the approver in the approval history will be the context user for the inbound email handler, which is a fixed user, and not something that can be set in your apex code.